# YII2 assets directory permission denied

Tags: yii2

I have a project from git, what says:

> Exception (Invalid Configuration) 'yii\base\InvalidConfigException'
> with message 'The directory is not writable by the Web process:
> /var/www/xxx.lh/web/assets'

In the `web` directory:

```
drwxr-sr-x  7 vaso vaso 4096 márc  31 08:22 .
drwxr-sr-x 17 vaso vaso 4096 márc  31 08:25 ..
drwxr-sr-x  2 vaso vaso 4096 márc  31 08:22 assets
drwxr-sr-x  2 vaso vaso 4096 márc  31 08:22 css
-rw-r--r--  1 vaso vaso  318 márc  31 08:22 favicon.ico
drwxr-sr-x  2 vaso vaso 4096 márc  31 08:22 fonts
-rw-r--r--  1 vaso vaso  199 márc  31 08:22 .htaccess
drwxr-sr-x  2 vaso vaso 4096 márc  31 08:22 images
-rw-r--r--  1 vaso vaso  367 márc  31 08:22 index.php
-rw-r--r--  1 vaso vaso  498 márc  31 08:22 index-test.php
drwxr-sr-x  3 vaso vaso 4096 márc  31 08:22 js
-rw-r--r--  1 vaso vaso   23 márc  31 08:22 robots.txt
```

The `nginx.conf` starts with this:

```
user vaso vaso;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;
include /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/*.conf;
....
```

Checking the processes:

```
ps -aux | grep nginx
root     13222  0.0  0.0 144508  3176 ?        Ss   08:17   0:00 nginx: master process /usr/sbin/nginx -g daemon on; master_process on;
vaso     13223  0.0  0.1 147008 11256 ?        S    08:17   0:00 nginx: worker process
vaso     13224  0.0  0.0 146804  7856 ?        S    08:17   0:00 nginx: worker process
vaso     13225  0.0  0.0 146804  7856 ?        S    08:17   0:00 nginx: worker process
vaso     13226  0.0  0.0 146804  7856 ?        S    08:17   0:00 nginx: worker process
vaso     13227  0.0  0.0 146804  7856 ?        S    08:17   0:00 nginx: worker process
vaso     13228  0.0  0.0 146804  7856 ?        S    08:17   0:00 nginx: worker process
```

What can be the problem? Temporary I can set `777` for that directory, but that is not a solution, because in production `755` has set. `775` does not helps also.

Comment: What about user in php-fpm config?

Comment: I think you need to create/change the user/group permission nested of change permission directory, if you do that you can safe push it to production without issue...

Comment: You can try this: 

chmod -R 0755 assest
chown www-data:www-data -R assests
or
chown userUser:www-data -R assests

Comment: @MichalHynčica You were right. If you add it as an answer, I'll accept.

Comment: @vaso123 I don't have much experience with nginx/php-fpm configuration to turn it into proper answer with configuration examples to help someone in future. I've just thought that it's probably php-fpm running the php scripts not nginx itself. Please feel free to add it as answer yourself or maybe someone else with experience can make it into proper answer.